# AWS CloudFront signed cookies returning MalformedSignature

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to protect my Single Page App (SPA) behind CloudFront signed cookies. I have it setting the cookies in the browser, however whenever I try and access the page it says MalformedSignature (I'll also attach a picture at the bottom). I know my Public Key and Private Key are correct, because I can generate signed URL's with no problem. Here is my code for generating the cookies:

```
const cloudFront = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer('KEY_ID_HERE', PRIVATE_KEY);

const expTime = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 1);

const policy = JSON.stringify({
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": "https://app.domain.click/*",
            "Condition": {
                "DateLessThan": {
                    "AWS:EpochTime": expTime// Current Time in UTC + time in seconds, (60 * 60 * 1 = 1 hour)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

const cookie = cloudFront.getSignedCookie({
    policy: policy
});
```

Another weird thing is that, if I try and load my index.html page by setting query params Policy, Signature, and Key-Pair-Id using the cookie values I get, I can see that my index page is loading correctly, but it is not able to load the scripts included in that file.

`https://app.domain.click/index.html?Policy=policy_here&Signature=Signature_here&Key-Pair-Id=key_pair_id_here` (This is loads the index.html file only).

I'll also attach pictures of the Behavior in my distribution.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So this is embarrassing... I had a new line character in the cookie and the reason I didn't catch it earlier was because it looked like the text editor I was using was moving the text to the next line. In fact, it was not and as soon as I removed the new line it started working.